# What functions do the order of Django Managers affect?

Tags: python, django, django-managers

So, I've read most of the docs and I've been looking around on SO a bit, but I can't quite find the answer to my question. I'll start with the code.

```
# Manager
class ActiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ActiveManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_active=True)
```

```
# Model
class ModelA(models.Model):
    # ...
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    objects = ActiveManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```

So, while I was playing around I noticed that if I wrote it this way and used `get_object_or_404()`, then it would use the `ActiveManager` to first search for all active records and then return the one related to my query. However, if I switched the order of the managers:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    # ...
    all_objects = models.Manager()
    objects = ActiveManager()
```

Then it uses the default manager, in this case `all_objects`, to do the query. I'm wondering what other functions does this change impact.

EDIT: I understand that the first manager found in the class becomes the default manager, but I'm wondering which specific functions use this default manager (like `get_object_or_404`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the relevant bit from the docs: ["If you use custom `Manager` objects, take note that the first `Manager` Django encounters (in the order in which they're defined in the model) has a special status. Django interprets the first `Manager` defined in a class as the "default" `Manager`, and several parts of Django (including `dumpdata`) will use that `Manager` exclusively for that model. As a result, it's a good idea to be careful in your choice of default manager in order to avoid a situation where overriding `get_query_set()` results in an inability to retrieve objects you'd like to work with"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets).

If you look at [the way `get_object_or_404` is implemented](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/shortcuts/__init__.py#L87), they use the `_default_manager` attribute of the model, which is how Django refers to the first manager encountered. (As far as I know, all Django internals work this way -- they never use `Model.objects` etc. because you shouldn't assume the default manager happens to be called `objects`).

Comment: Yea, I read that but I was wondering which specific things would use _default_manager so I can be on the look out for them. The most common ones would probably be good enough

Comment: @Bryce Siedschlaw, the only place in the code where I found Django referring to the `objects` attribute of a model (that is, one passed in dynamically -- of course they use `User.objects`, `Site.objects` etc.) is [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/generic/create_update.py#L78) (but function-based generic views are deprecated anyway). In particular, generic views use `_default_manager` by default.

Comment: You don't by chance know off-hand of any specific, commonly-used functions that would use the `_default_manager`, would you? Like `get_object_or_404`.

Comment: @Bryce Siedschlaw -- `get_list_or_404`, some generic views (e.g. `ListView`, `DetailView`) if you specify the model instead of a queryset),

Comment: yea... that's all I could really find too. Neither of which I actually use, but it's good to know nonetheless. I guess I'll find out if there are any surprises. If I do, I'll post em up here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It effects many things. The default name for the manager, `objects`, is just that, a default, but it's not required. If you didn't include `objects` in your model definition and just defined a manager as `all_objects`, `ModelA.objects` wouldn't exist. Django merely assigns a default manager to that if no other managers are present on the model and you have not defined `objects` on your own.

Anyways, because of this Django takes the first manager defined in a model and calls that the "default", and later uses the "default" manager anytime is needs to reference the model's manager (because, again, it can't simply use `objects` because `objects` might not be defined).

The rule of thumb is that the standard manager that Django should use (in a sense, the manager that should most normally be used), should be the first one defined, whether it be assigned to `objects` or something else entirely. Every other additional manager should come after that.

Comment: Like I told isbadawi, I've read those parts of the docs and understand all that. I was just wondering which specific functions use the default manager of a model (like `get_object_or_404`). That way I can track them down and make sure they're doing what I want. That's my fault for not specifying in the question.

Comment: I think the point we're both making is that it's everything. Django never directly calls `objects`. So any method that does a lookup will use the default manager, whatever that is.